# Embed in taskbar

Tags: c#, taskbar

How can I "embed" my application into the windows taskbar (not the systray) like in the picture below?

I would like to create a quick application that embeds into the taskbar.

[image: http://www.osirisdevelopment.com/BatteryBar/BatteryBar2-Discharge.png]
<sub>(source: [osirisdevelopment.com](http://www.osirisdevelopment.com/BatteryBar/BatteryBar2-Discharge.png))</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a [Desk Band](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969320.aspx)

There is an MSDN article explaining through the link.

There is also some previously written source code, originally on code project but now appears to have been taken down, there is a download link [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=297633)

I cant garuntee anything on this source I have not downloaded it, its your call but will hopefully be of use.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know they were called deskbands, now google is giving me much better results by using that term :)

Comment: I get that all the time, its a vicious circle, you dont know the correct term so you wind up searching with what you discover to be exremely vauge search terms and getting not alot! 

Glad to help, good luck!